# How to create a release with YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am converting a YAML build pipeline + classic release pipeline to a multi-stage YAML build/release pipeline. It appears to work, but I notice that in the build details, there is a Release tab that wasn't there before, and more to the point, that this tab is empty, as the screenshot shows.

I assume that I should preferably get something on this tab, to ensure that releases are similarly retained and as readily re-deployable as with classic release pipelines.

What should be on this tab, and what do I need to do to get it working?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this seems to be connected to the build pipeline's classic release pipeline (which is still there; I just disabled the automatic release creation). The tab was there also before I converted to a YAML release pipeline, and then the tab listed the (classic) releases that were created.